# Pandas groupby 0 value if does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a code like this

```
frame[frame['value_text'].str.match('Type 2')  | frame['value_text'].str.match('Type II diabetes')].groupby(['value_text','gender'])['value_text'].count()
```

which returns a series like

```
value_text            gender      count
type 2                  M           4
type 2 without...       M           4
                        F           3
```

what I want is

```
 value_text               gender      count
    type 2                  M           4
                            F           0
    type 2 without...       M           4
                            F           3
```

I want to include count for all genders even though there is no record in the dataframe. how can I do this?

Comment: Can't test, so a guess. Change the order of `.groupby(['value_text','gender'])`

Comment: it didn't show 0 count for missing.

Comment: So the output was unchanged or did it show something else?

Comment: it showed something else but not the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending `.unstack().fillna(0).stack()` to your current line, like so:

```
frame[frame['value_text'].str.match('Type 2')  |
      frame['value_text'].str.match('Type II diabetes')]\
.groupby(['value_text','gender'])['value_text'].count()\
.unstack().fillna(0).stack()
```

Answer (score 4):

[Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) was introduced in `pandas` specifically for this purpose.

In effect, `groupby` operations with categorical data automatically calculate the Cartesian product.

You should see additional benefits compared to other functional methods: lower memory usage and data validation.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'value_text': ['type2', 'type2 without', 'type2'],
                   'gender': ['M', 'F', 'M'],
                   'value': [1, 2, 3]})

df['gender'] = df['gender'].astype('category')

res = df.groupby(['value_text', 'gender']).count()\
        .fillna(0).astype(int)\
        .reset_index()

print(res)

      value_text gender  value
0          type2      F      0
1          type2      M      2
2  type2 without      F      1
3  type2 without      M      0
```

Comment: Amazing, this answer helped me solve my problem! Thanks @jpp

Answer (score 1):

Remember, whenever you want to force a specific list to index/shape your data. *Pivot*, *crosstab*, *stack*, *unstack* are not reliable since they highly depend on the input data. For example, if 'M' is never shown in any input row, you will not see 'M' no matter how you pivot/unstack your result. This kind of problem is where **reindex()** shines.

Assume your pre-processed frame is saved as **df**:

```
  mdx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], ['M', 'F']])
  df.reindex(mdx1).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

On the other hand, if you just want all possible level-1 values to be shown in all level-0, do the following:

```
  mdx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels)
  df.reindex(mdx1).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

This can be easily extended to dataframes with more than 2-level indexes.

*Update:* use Categorical data-type might fix the problems pivot-like functions have.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is with `pd.crosstab` and then `stack`:

```
# save your filtered dataframe as an intermediate result, for convenience
type2 = frame[frame.value_text.str.match('Type 2|Type II diabetes')]

pd.crosstab(type2.value_text, type2.gender).stack()
```